# What resources detail other planets in the Pathfinder Campaign Setting

Tags: pathfinder-1e, campaign-settings

I recently came across the other planets of the Pathfinder Campaign setting.  I see that they are only briefly described in the setting book.  What other resources exist that describe the other planets in Golarion's star system?

As an edit, I'm looking for modules as well as reference.  I saw that one of the Reign of Winter modules has some solar travel, are there any others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

People of the Stars and Distant Worlds come immediately to mind- the former focuses more on noteworthy alien races in the Pathfinder universe, including many playable ones, while the latter concerns itself more with the planets themselves than what lives on them.

Answer (score 2):

Pathfinder Second Darkness book 2: Children of the Void
Starting on page 48 there is various material about the other planets in the solar system.